# Run scripts on user login, but before session (Linux)?

Tags: rsync, ubuntu-12.04

Does anyone know of a way to do the following on Linux.  I can't seem to find a way to run a script after the user is authenticated, but before the session starts...

- User types username and password into GDM, LightDM, TTY, etc.
- Rsync pulls their user's profile from a central server
- User's session starts and they complete the days work normally
- User logs out
- Rsync updates user's profile on server

I can easily script everything listed above, I just don't know where to put the scripts to do this...

QA:

"Why not use NFS/CIFS/other-nas-protocol?"

High latency network, and spotty connection at times...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pam-script](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/pam-script.7.html) looks like a solution. A quote from the man page:

> pam-script allows you to execute scripts during authorization, passwd changes, and on session opening or closing.
>
> Such scripts can perform necessary tasks or influence the outcome of the PAM stack. For example, if the following entry was included in pam.conf
>
> ```
>   sshd auth required pam_script
> ```
>
> then if the script, pam_script_auth, exits with a non-zero value this would cause the user to be denied SSH access to the machine.